# Display featured images on a different page wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to be able to display featured images (category 4 in my wordpress site) on a separate page just the images not the rest of the post.

I created a template named 'ban' and attached it to a page named banners in which to display the category 4 images.

I was able to list the categories but that is as far as I got:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('include=4') ?>
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, if someone could explain it to me it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all featured images from the posts under category 4 then this might be the solution

```
$the_query = new WP_Query();
$the_query->query("cat=4&nopaging=true");
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

      if(has_post_thumbnail()) : 
        the_post_thumbnail();
      endif;

endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If you want to get the real width/height of then images you can use this:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
?>
<img src='<?php echo $image[0]; ?>' />
<?php
```

Just replace the the_post_thumbnail() function. Hope that helps!

Comment: I get back to work tomorrow as soon as I give it a shot I will let you know my results. Thank you!

Comment: I got it to display just have another question, what do I replace the _post_thumnail() funtion with? Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want to display the image in its whole size then you can replace it with the code at the bottom of my answer. :)